# serilog unique logger asp.net webform 4.8

Tags: c#, asp.net, serilog, .net-4.8

How can I add q unique serilog logger in my webform app ?
Because I am doing this in the Load and it is create a new logfile everyTime. I want to log in a same log file.
I am using 4.8 .net framework

```
     public partial class TransferForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.File(
                  _logFilePath, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, 
                   rollOnFileSizeLimit: true
                         )
            .CreateLogger();
            _logger = Log.Logger;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Even if you put the code in the Program/Main, you need to consider how you're hosting the application. If IIS terminates your app pool when idling, it will run the code again on next visit.

Comment: try to add `shared: true` in the `WriteTo.File(..)` call.